# Return the calling function

Tags: c#

I use C# for testing purpose. A test consists of several test steps. If one test step fails, the whole test should be aborted. One test step could look like this:

```
Variable1.Value = 1;
Variable1.write();

Variable1.read();
if (Variable1.Value != 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Fail");
    return;  //this return aborts the test
}
//next test steps
```

I'd like to transfer some commands into own functions to allow efficient test case programming. The function for the code above would look like this.

```
private void verifyValue (TypeOfVariable Var, double Value)
{
    Var.read();
    if (Var.Value != Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Fail");
        return;
    }
}
```

And the test would look like this

```
Variable1.Value = 1;
Variable1.write();
verifyValue(Variable1, 1);
//next test steps
```

My Problem is now, that the `return` in function `verifyValue` only effects `verifyValue` but not the calling function (aka test).

Is there any possibility to abort the calling function?

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't using a unit testing framework and `Assert`?

Comment: You are trying to implement an atomic operation by using return statements and function completion. I think this is not a very good approach. Instead, you can implement classes which execute all statements as a transaction and based on the exceptions they throw, you can abort or continue the operation.

Comment: Unless your example is very bad I agree with @Slavo. This is not how to implement what you're trying to achieve. On saying that, an expensive, but possible option, is throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

This is typically done via [**Exceptions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx). They propagate through the call stack automatically. Here's an example based on your code:

```
public class TestFailedException : Exception
{
    public TestFailedException(string message) : base(message) { }
}

void Test()
{
    try 
    {
        Variable1.Value = 1;
        Variable1.write();
        verifyValue(Variable1, 1);

        //next test steps
        ...

        Console.WriteLine("Test succeeded");
    }
    catch (TestFailedException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test failed: " + ex.Message);
    }
}

private void verifyValue(TypeOfVariable Var, double Value)
{
    Var.read();
    if (Var.Value != Value)
    {
        throw new TestFailedException("Actual value: " + Var.Value.ToString()
            + ", expected value: " + Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better if you use Transaction and then on any exception abort all the operation. For your current code you can through an exception and let the program stop itself. like:

```
throw new Exception("Test Failed - Stopping the program execution");
```